# How to count number of files in a folder in a remote host with a php file in localhost?

Tags: php, file, localhost, glob

I want to count number of files in a folder in a remote host. The path is traversable. The file which I want to check with is in localhost?
How to do that?
I couldn't find an example that uses glob function to get files in a remote host. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot execute code at a remote host. A better solution would be to place a script that counts the files and echos the number at the remote host, then do:

```
$num_files = file_get_contents('http://remoteaddr/count_files.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

You either need a php files on the remote machine or you would have to look into PHP's [ftp functionality](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php).

Answer (score 0):

```
function count_files($user, $host, $dir_path) {
    $command = "ssh {$user}@{$host} ls -l {$dir_path} | wc -l";
    $res = (int)system($command);
    return $res - 1;
}
```